# Symfony getRootDir() + /../folder/file.ext (file_get_contents) not found

Tags: symfony

I am virtually at a brick wall with Symfony, I have a folder at /../compiled/ with some minified files, and the controller is configured to get files from getRootDir() + /../compiled/file.min.css

However, it just throws out an exception 'file not found' when call file_get_contents(file) even when the file actually exists.

I just don't know what is wrong, it is such a cryptic problem.

**Code as requested:**

```html
 public function atpInitAction(Request $request) // Validates the origin.
    {
        $content = null; $_file = $request->query->get('file');
        if ($_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] == atpHandler::getDomain())
        {
            // I AM FROM THE ORIGIN...
            $webfolder = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../compiled';
            $_file = $webfolder."/".$_file;
        }

        // What's my mime?
        $_mime = 'text/plain';
        if ($_file[strlen($_file)-2] == 'j') { $_mime = 'text/javascript'; }
        else { $_mime = 'text/css'; }

        $response = new Response();
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', $_mime);
        $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'filename="'.basename($_file) . '";');
        $response->headers->set('Content-Length', filesize($_file));
        $response->setContent(file_get_contents($_file));
        $response->sendHeaders();
        return $response;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure the file exists in that path ? does file_exists(path) confirms that your file exists ? Maybe you're providing a wrong path, therefore file_get_contents doesn't works. In which folder is exactly located your file.min.css (provide full filepath)?

Comment: The root directory is /var/www (and inside this folder is /compiled which contains frontend.min.css) when I check from the terminal the file exists, but does_file_exist fails. I have even chmod with full permission, and tried running under root. The fullpath: /var/www/compiled/frontend.min.css

Comment: Can you post your code please?

Comment: Why would a Symfony controller be trying to get the contents of a css file?

Comment: Code has been attached, and the reason being to prevent hotlinking, it verifies the request is from my domain.

Comment: does `/../compiled` mean `/SOMETHING/compiled` or your literally saying go above a `dir`?? In later case. I'd suggest you to do just `/compiled`

Comment: @Nishanth Martha, I am going to add this into my notes for testing and see what results I get. I also found I might need to wrap the path within realpath(...) but will report back soon.

Comment: It is possible that the `getRootDir` function isn't pointing to the default root directory i.e. `/var/www/app`. Have you ruled out that possibility?